# How to assign javascript variable with id of a link tag before going to the link

Tags: javascript

How do I hijack a link tag and assign a variable with id of a link tag before going to the url?

MY HTML Code

```
<div id="course" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><a href="read.html" id="m1">Course 1</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><a href="read.html" id="m2">Course 2</a></div>
<div>
```

MY JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
document.getElementById("course").addEventListener("click", courseInfo);

function courseInfo(){

    var selectedCourse = the id of the course selected;

    //assign to localstorage
    localStorage.setItem("courseid", selectedCourse);
    //go to courseinfo.html
    window.location.href = 'courseinfo.html';

}
```

I'm trying to get the Id of the course and the set it to the local storage so that when the courseinfo.html is loaded if will make request ajax and parse the course json format to fill the page.

Please help

Comment: That is not how you should try to do it. Instead change the URL in the `href` attribute to include a parameter, like `read.html?id=m1`.

Comment: like adding `courseinfo.html?courseid=1` is that possible in html? if that possible how do i process those `courseinfo.html?courseid=1` with javascript?

Comment: I would use the `onClick` event to invoke a function that performs two tasks: assign the link to a variable, GOTO the like. Note, however, that going to a different page would cause a full context refresh and hence your variable will be dropped.

Comment: @FDavidov that why I'm assigning it to local storage because on the other page I plan to retrieve it to a variable.

Comment: In that case, the approach I'm suggestion should do the job.

Comment: Ok this is stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `localStorage` for this, but just pass the information via a URL argument:

On the first page, put the course code in the `href` URL, like this:

```
<div id="course" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><a href="courseinfo.html?courseid=1" id="m1">Course 1</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><a href="courseinfo.html?courseid=2" id="m2">Course 2</a></div>
<div>
```

No JavaScript is needed for that to work.

Then on the receiving page, capture the course id as follows:

```
var courseid = location.search.match(/[&?]courseid=(.*?)(&|$)/);
if (courseid) courseid = courseid[1]; // get captured group

// this would output "1" if the URL argument was `courseid=1`
console.log(courseid);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @trincot suggested you can do this on the receiving end.

If, however, you do need to capture the id of the clicked link when it is clicked, you need to add the event handler on the links themselves and then use the event recieved to handle the data, like so

```
var x;
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("A");

for(x in links) {
    if (links[x] instanceof Element) {
        links[x].addEventListener('click',doX, false);
    }
}

function doX(e) {
    alert(e.currentTarget.id);
}
```

Please note that on fast browsers, the browser may not completely finish running `doX` before the page gets refreshed and the context vanishes, so this not a very safe method to do things, unless you prevent the default action using `e.preventDefault` and handle the link yourself.